# Get checked values in dynamic primeng checkbox

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, checkbox, primeng

I have an array of questions, with each question having a question field and an options field which is essentially an array of string options. **The app is being build in Angular.**

```
{

  question: "Is this the question?",
  options: ["yes", "no", "maybe", "not sure"]

}
```

The questions are received from a service dynamically, and may change over time. The user must have the option to select more than one options, hence I am using a checkbox. Specifically,  PrimeNG's checkbox.

```
<p-checkbox #checkbox class="checkbox-option" [label]="opt.val" [value]="opt.val" value="opt.val">
</p-checkbox>
```

The question being, which approach should be used in order to receive the checked options of one question at a time. The checkbox would have a submit button below, after which I'll need to check the checked options.

*PS. I am new, if anyone needs any other relevant imformation or piece of code, just notify me. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use ngModel in your elements, then you can just pull the selected values easily.
Here's an example with a loop

```
<p-checkbox *ngFor="let opt of boxes" class="checkbox-option" 
  [label]="opt.val" 
  [value]="opt.val" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedBoxes" >
    </p-checkbox>

<button (click)="getSelected()">Get answers</button>
```

in component.ts

```
export class SomeComponent { 
    selectedBoxes: string[] = [];
    getSelected() {
          console.log(this.selectedBoxes)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, like I said, the questions are received from the service and the checkbox is generated dynamically, hence something simple like this will not work.